# How to differentiate discrete probabilities?

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations

Assuming that I have a function 
$$f(p(x),p(c),p(x,c)) = \ln (p(x)p(c)) + \ln (p(x,c))$$

where $p(\cdot)$ are discrete probabilities, $x \in X, c \in C$ are random variables. So $p(x)=p(X=x)$ denotes probability of $x$ occurring, $p(x,c)=p(X=x,C=c)$ denotes probability of $x,c$ occurring together.

If I differentiate this function with respect to $p(x,c)$, how do I differentiate the term $ln (p(x)p(c))$ wrt $p(x,c)$?

Do I have to do partial differentiation 
$$\frac{\partial \ln (p(x)p(c))}{\partial p(x)}\frac{\partial (p(x))}{\partial p(x,c)}+\frac{\partial \ln (p(x)p(c))}{\partial p(c)}\frac{\partial (p(c))}{\partial p(x,c)}$$

or differentiation of this term wrt $p(x,c)$ is zero?

Comment: What are the discrete probabilities? Are you familiar with partial derivatives? What such differentiation shall give you as an outcome?

Comment: The discrete probabilities are simply obtained from a discrete data. I am not familiar with partial derivatives. My guess is differentiate $ln (p(x)p(c))$ wrt $p(c,x)$ is zero, but it seems that $p(x)p(c)$ and $p(x,c)$ are related, but they are not governed by a formula or equation, so I do not know how to do partial differentiation on them

Comment: If those are partial derivatives, it is zero, but since there is certainly a dependence between these values - I asked you why do you need to differentiate them. Clarifying that point would help.

Comment: @Ilya my function is to measure a characteristic of the data, and I am wondering what will be the optimal probabilities to get the maximum of the function, or if given a probability, what is the gradient of the function to reach the maximum of the function, To get the maximum of the function, I am thinking of getting its gradient

Comment: Presumably $p(x,c)$ and $p(c,x)$ are meant to be the same thing? It would be slightly less confusing if you stick to one of them.

Comment: Now it's even more confusing; you've changed two of the three occurrences but left one standing.

Comment: I am so sorry, I try to add more explanations now. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer below is very general and doesn't take into account what emerged in later clarifications of the question. It treats $p(x)$, $p(c)$ and $p(x,c)$ as unknown entities. With the clarifications provided, $f$ needs to be considered as a function of many more variables, namely all $p(x,c')$ and all $p(x',c)$. All derivatives should then be partial derivatives, and we can take the derivative of $f$ with respect to $p(x,c)$ while keeping all other $p(x',c)$ and $p(x,c')$ constant. With $p(x)=\sum_cp(x,c)$ and $p(c)=\sum_xp(x,c)$, we have $\partial p(c)/\partial p(x,c)=1$ and $\partial p(x)/\partial p(x,c)=1$, so

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x,c)}=\frac1{p(x,c)}+\frac1{p(x)}+\frac1{p(c)}\;.
$$

(You'll need a Lagrange multiplier for the normalization constraint if you take this approach.)

---

It depends entirely on how you're viewing these probabilities. If you have a model where $p(x)$, $p(c)$ and $p(x,c)$ can be varied separately, you can treat them as distinct independent variables and just take the partial derivative with respect to any of them, e.g. $\partial f/\partial p(x,c)=1/p(x,c)$.

On the other hand, if your model posits some relationship between them, you have to take that relationship into account. If $p(x)$ and $p(c)$ can be expressed as functions of $p(x,c)$, you can form the *total* derivative with respect to $p(x,c)$, and the result is similar but not quite the same as what you wrote:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm df}{\mathrm dp(x,c)}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x,c)}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x)}\frac{\mathrm dp(x)}{\mathrm dp(x,c)}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(c)}\frac{\mathrm dp(c)}{\mathrm dp(x,c)}
\\
&=\frac1{p(x,c)}+\frac1{p(x)}\frac{\mathrm dp(x)}{\mathrm dp(x,c)}+\frac1{ p(c)}\frac{\mathrm dp(c)}{\mathrm dp(x,c)}\;.
\end{align}
$$

Theoretically you could also consider *two* of the three as independent and have only one relationship expressing the third in terms of them; in that case, "differentiating with respect to $p(x,c)$" is only well-defined if you specify which of the two others you're holding constant. Then you can form a *partial* derivative with respect to $p(x,c)$, which you can also obtain with the chain rule. For instance, if you want to differentiate with respect to $p(x,c)$ while holding $p(x)$ constant, that would be

$$
\begin{align}
\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x,c)}\right|_{p(x)}&=\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x,c)}\left.\frac{\partial p(x,c)}{\partial p(x,c)}\right|_{p(x)}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x)}\left.\frac{\partial p(x)}{\partial p(x,c)}\right|_{p(x)}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(c)}\left.\frac{\partial p(c)}{\partial p(x,c)}\right|_{p(x)}
\\
&=
\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(x,c)}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial p(c)}\left.\frac{\partial p(c)}{\partial p(x,c)}\right|_{p(x)}
\\
&=
\frac1{p(x,c)}+\frac1{p(c)}\left.\frac{\partial p(c)}{\partial p(x,c)}\right|_{p(x)}\;,
\end{align}
$$

where the unqualified partial derivatives are the standard partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to its three arguments while keeping the other two constant.

Comment: I only know the $p(x,c)$ is the joint probability of random variable $x,c$. Is there a way to express $p(x),p(c)$ as function of $p(x,c)$?

Comment: in discrete case $p(x) = \sum_c p(x,c)$

Comment: @Michael: Does Ilya's comment reflect what you had in mind? If so, the formulas can be simplified considerably. By the way, you should have mentioned right away that $x$, $c$ are random variables; I was taking them to be events.

Comment: @joriki: I apologise for missing the details. So given that I have $p(x)=\sum_c p(x,c)$ (thank you Ilya), I can differentiate $\frac{\partial p(x)}{\partial p(x,c')}=\frac{\partial \sum_c p(x,c)}{\partial p(x,c')}$?

Comment: @joriki: I think your total derivative is what I needed, and with the relationship $p(x) = \sum_c p(x,c)$, $p(c) = \sum_x p(x,c)$, I can plug these relationships into your total derivative to get my gradient

Comment: @Michael: Yes, and note that $\frac{\partial\sum_c p(x,c)}{\partial p(x,c')}=\sum_c\frac{\partial p(x,c)}{\partial p(x,c')}=\frac{\partial p(x,c')}{\partial p(x,c')}=1$. (However, note that the total derivative $\frac{d\sum_c p(x,c)}{dp(x,c')}=\sum_c\frac{dp(x,c)}{dp(x,c')}$ may well _not_ equal 1, if changing $p(x,c')$ also affects the other probabilities. In particular, given the constraint that $\sum_x\sum_c p(x,c)=1$, not _all_ the probabilities can vary completely independently.)

Comment: @Michael: I've added a bit at the top to adapt the previously very general answer to your specific question. Please take more care in initially describing the setting of your question next time.

Comment: @joriki: thank you very much for your help. I will be careful in the future. Can you elaborate more on the normalization constraint?

Comment: @Michael: As Ilmari wrote, you can't vary all the probabilities independently, since they have to add up to $1$. If I've now correctly understood what you're doing, you're considering the individual probabilities $p(x,c)$ as variables to be fitted to some data; if you want to do that by optimizing some function of all the $p(x,c)$, you need to perform a constrained optimization using a Lagrange term $\lambda\sum_{x,c}p(x,c)$ with a Lagrange multiplier $\lambda$ to take into account the normalization constraint $\sum_{x,c}p(x,c)=1$.

Comment: @joriki: yes. I haven't think in depth about the problem. I'm thinking since the constraint is linear, I can use the elimination of variable method to simplify the constrained optimization problem into an unconstrained optimization problem

Comment: @Michael: That destroys the symmetry of the problem and doubles the number of terms in the derivatives, since every single variable occurs in what you substitute for the eliminated one. I haven't thought it all through, but I'd be surprised if this offered any benefits over the Lagrange multiplier approach, which preserves the symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have only a finite number of $p(x)$, $p(c)$ and $p(x,c)$ it's possible just to find the maximum of their function $f$ directly, however I agree it may not be optimal. In such case it's worth looking where $f(p,q,r)$ has its maximum and picking up discrete values closest (in some sense) to the argument of the maximum $(p^*,q^*,r^*)$. Provided the fact that $\ln$ has some Lipschitz properties, the found solution shall not be bad.

However, it matters here *where* are you looking for the maximum. In case all three value are independent, you shall just look for it on $[0,1]^3$. In such case you have just a maximum of a sum of 3 independent $\ln$ and it is easy to find.

However, in case there is a certain dependence - you shall look for the conditional maximum. E.g. if you know that $|p(x,c)-p(x)p(c)|\leq \varepsilon$, you shall look for the maximum only on 
$$
  [0,1]^3\cap \{(p,q,r):|r-pq|\leq \varepsilon\}.
$$
Or if you know that $p(x,c) = g(p(x),p(c))$ then you shall look for the maximum of
$$
  f(p,q,g(p,q))
$$
on $[0,1]^2$. Without knowing the underlying statistical problem, it's hard to say which kind of dependence you shall have.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, much appreciated